# Index every values in numpy where duplicate values has same index

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, indexing

I am having below numpy array

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['i123', 'i314', 'i123', 'i543','i2341'])
```

Performing the sorting operation on this array

```
x_sort = np.sort(x)

print(x_sort)
['i123' 'i123' 'i2341' 'i314' 'i543']
```

Now I want an array that represent index of **x_sort** in below way

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

where 0 for 'i123' , 1 for 'i234' and so on.

Can anyone help me to achieve this in fastest possible way using numpy as I am having a data set that contains millions of these records.

Comment: So, is `x_sort` given or is it part of the solution?

Comment: part of solution

Comment: Just use `np.unique` with `return_inverse` arg.

Comment: Do you want the indices sorted or in the original order [0,2,0,3,1]?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I want them in the original order

Comment: In that case @Divakar's solution is the one to go for.